# Terminal Closes Immediately on Open 14.04

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

I tried to follow other answers on here that I found but I cannot stop my terminal from closing as soon as it opens on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Here are my profile files.

[`.bashrc`](http://pastebin.com/R4CbeVk4)
[`.profile`](http://pastebin.com/QWd3AajY)
[`/etc/bash.bashrc`](http://pastebin.com/ZD0rK7ME)
[`/etc/profile`](http://pastebin.com/EqNhUAjR)

Environment is simply

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Thanks for your help.

Seems to only happen after adding my user to the `sftp` user group. My other account worked fine until I did this.

Comment: If you move these files somewhere else, do you have the same problem? If so, they are not the cause of it. If you try with another user, do you have the same problem? If so, the problem is not user-specific.

Comment: It doesn't do it on a guest user, I don't have any other users. And if I move the files it still does it.

Comment: Did you try moving those files somewhere else?

Comment: Yes sorry I did it does the same thing.

Comment: So, they are not the problem. What else did you change in the terminal from the default? Like profile and such? Install another terminal, like `xterm`, and try to launch `gnome-terminal` from there. Does it give any error? Does it work?

Comment: Did you modify terminal preference ? I am talking about that popup window where you set color, background, etc. This is frequent problem  when users modify the "Run custom command " part

Comment: Xterm doesn't open, Konsole doesn't work (closes immediately). I did not modify any settings. All I've done is set up my IRC bouncer, MySecureShell SFTP server, and my Plex Media Server. It might be a residual setting from an old install because I've carried over my home directory.

Comment: The problem is not in either of those files. Please [edit] your question and add the contents of `~/.bash_login`, `~/bash_aliases`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `/etc/profile` and `/etc/environment`. If any of these files doesn't exist, ignore it. Also, try creating a new user, can the new user open a terminal?

Comment: A new user can open the terminal, yes. I'll post what I have, thanks.

Comment: I can't post more than two links so here's one more. /etc/bash.bashrc http://pastebin.com/ZD0rK7ME and another /etc/profile http://pastebin.com/EqNhUAjR

Answer (score -2):

Your problem is that, by the time you open a terminal, the `i` flag is no longer set in '$-'. Replace:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

with:

```
# If not running interactively, remember
case $- in
    *i*) IsInteractive=1;;
      *) IsInteractive=0;;
esac
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am having the same issue after making these changes and rebooting.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the `case` statement. The `return` just means that the rest of the file is not read, not that the shell will exit.